# Realtime forms in Django

Tags: jquery, python, django

I have a website and I want to have a form on the website that multiple people can view. As the firm gets updated by any of the individuals looking at it, everyone else can also see the updates without refreshing the web page. Basically it will be a row from a table displayed as a form and each part of the form will be filled periodically and will all start off empty

I was thinking jquery might be able to do this but I do not fully understand everything about jquery yet.

Any thoughts or ideas on the best way to do this? I am currently just learning django as I go.

Answer (score 0):

I think ajax should do the trick for you